# Dell PowerEdge R710 enters BIOS setup during each boot

Tags: boot, bios, dell-poweredge

Our Dell PowerEdge R710 enters BIOS setup during each boot. We have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to continue booting. How can we ensure that the server boots without user intervention?

During POST the server does not print any suspicious messages. In the setup we have not found any settings which could be related to the problem. The BIOS version is 2.1.15. The problem appears both on the local console and when connected over iDRAC.

The only suspicious message during boot is: `BIOS installed successfully!` but most probably this is a message of the BIOS of the Adaptec RAID 2405 controller. Then iDRAC 6 shows its messages and then the BIOS setup shows up.

Comment: Call Dell technical support.

Comment: @joeqwerty: Unfortunately the server is not covered by a support any more but finally we have found a solution. See my reply below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally by trial and error we have discovered the problem. It was in the iDRAC setting. We turned off this setting in the iDRAC web interface:

```
System > Setup > First Boot Device > Boot Once
```

[image]

After turning the option off the server boots normally.